# Difference between href="#!" and href="#"

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I confused after showing the HTML line while surfing the materialize design framework:

```
<a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a>
```

[Framework](http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html) MaterializeCss.

Why are they putting extra exclamation mark with `#`?

What is difference between `href="#"` and `href="#!"`?

Comment: Yes @Juhana it's seems duplicate of the mentioned question. Found one more interesting article.http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs